# How to start host & start service with two endpoint with WcfSvcHost.exe

Tags: wcf

i have one service with two endpoint. one endpoint is for wsdual binding and another for tcp binding. when i start my wcf service with wcfsvchost.exe like

```
WcfSvcHost.exe /service:"C:
\Users\TRIDIP\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BBAChatService\BBAChatService\bin
\BBAChatService.dll" /config:"C:\Users\TRIDIP\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects
\BBAChatService\BBAChatService\Web.config"
```

then my service was started but it is showing only one mex endpoint. it should show two mex endpoint because i have two endpoint declared in web.config file. here is my config file entry.

```
<service name="BBAChatService.ChatService" behaviorConfiguration="BBAChatService.ChatServiceBehavior" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="http://localhost:8732/ChatService.svc/"/>
            <add baseAddress ="net.tcp://localhost:7998/ChatService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint name="dual_bind"
                  address="dual"
                  binding="wsDualHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChatService" 
                  contract="BBAChatService.IChatService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

        <endpoint name="tcp_bind"
              address="tcp"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
              contract="BBAChatService.IChatService">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:7996/ChatService/mex"
                          binding="mexTcpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>


      </service>
```

is there anything i miss in config file. please guide me what i need to do as a result wcfsvchost will show two different endpoint for my service. thanks

Comment: Your config looks ok, just not sure wcfsvchost can host tcp endpoints.  Does it matter? You want to test your implementation with WcfSvcHost, not whether transports have been correctly configured, right?

Comment: The problem is when i am creating proxy with tcp mex endpoint then at client side config file added with all endpoints details....i just need to know why? i want that when i will create proxy with tcp mex endpoint or mexHttpBinding from client side then only valid endpoint should be added in client's config file. so guide me what to change in my config file at service end.